# Why does Excel treat these two identical looking cells as different?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an unusual problem, Excel is treating cells containing apparently equal values as if they're different.

To replicate the problem, I've attached a spreadsheet showing this behaviour [here](https://www.mediafire.com/?150bwc3qwj0jr2c).

If you don't want to download it, then this is what it looks like:

[image: Two apparently identical cells]

Excel is treating Cells A2 and B2 as if they're different, even though "G" is in both. Cell C2 is testing this with `=EXACT(A2,B2)`.

The real problem is that when I import this data into, say, R, it treats them as different and prevents proper analysis of the data.

In this case, I can delete those cells, retype "G" and they will now be the same, but I have a *huge* dataset where a lot of identical characters are being treated as different.

**What's causing this? And is there a quick way to automatically fix a larger version of this?**

Comment: You will find that there is unprintable characters like a space or carriage return in one or both of the cells.

Comment: @ScottCraner I see, it appears the person who sent me this spreadsheet inadvertently riddled it with trailing spaces - I guess I'll have to trim them all. If you feel like posting your comment as an answer I would accept it.

Comment: Correcting this issue may be easier if you export the sheet to a CSV file and edit with a good text editor (notepad++, sublime, et al). Then you can see the issue clearly and also do various replacements. (Note: CSV is not a good idea if there are formulas or special formatting you need to preserve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems like this are usually caused by the issue @ScottCraner has mentioned in the comments.  The reason for this is as follows...

Using the spreadsheet cutting you provided in your question, let's say...

- there is a space after the `G` in cell `A2`, and
- there is **not** a space after the `G` in cell `B2`

If this is the case, although visually to us they look the same...

- cell `A2` would be seen by excel to equal `"G "`, and
- cell `B2` would be seen by excel to equal `"G"`

Therefore, you would get `FALSE` in cell `C2`

You would need to trim and clean all cells containing trailing non printable characters (removing trailing and leading spaces, carriage returns etc.) to ensure consistency of data in cells.

You could do this manually by re-entering the value which should be there, however if you have a lot of cells which potentially have this problem, then creating a macro may be beneficial for time saving reasons.

**VBA to do the task**.

For a great bit of code you could use a fast code suggested by [The Spreadsheet Guru](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/a-fast-way-to-clean-trim-cell-values-with-vba-code) which is for

> handling trimming (removing leading and ending spaces) and cleaning (removing unprintable characters) processes for your Excel data.

```vb
Sub CleanTrimCells_Evaluate()
'PURPOSE: A Fast way to Clean/Trim cell values in user selection
'AUTHOR: Armando Montes
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

Dim rng As Range
Dim Area As Range

'Weed out any formulas from selection
  If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    Set rng = Selection
  Else
    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
  End If

'Trim and Clean cell values
  For Each Area In rng.Areas
    Area.Value = Evaluate("IF(ROW(" & Area.Address & "),CLEAN(TRIM(" & Area.Address & ")))")
  Next Area

End Sub
```